# Using a custom membership provider together with Web Site Adminstration Tool

Tags: asp.net, dependency-injection, asp.net-membership

I've made a custom `MembershipProvider` which uses `DependencyResolver` from MVC3 to find it's dependencies. It works great for MVC apps, but not for the Web Site Adminstration Tool.

Is there some way that I can hook into the Web Site Adminstration Tool request handling to be able to configure a container before it handles the request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Membership providers should be interoperable  and therefore should work just by plugging into the config file of any provider based app.

Web Site Adminstration tool does exactly this, it runs in it's own web application completely decoupled from your MVC app, and just references your provider.

To make this work you need to ensure all dependencies required for the membership provider are packaged in one assembly and bootstrap your IoC container regardless of the environment it runs in. You can code this in such a way to share MVC initialisation, but not depend on it.